# TamperMonkey setTimeout ID быстро прыгает в начале почему?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На всех сайтах когда запускаю данный скрипт с помощью tamperMonkey

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         My Fancy New Userscript2
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.google.com/
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==
var timer = 0;
function test() {
    console.log(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(test, 5000);
}
test();
```

то в консоле вижу:

```
0
16
42
73
98
110
...
251
252
253
```

В начале большие скачки ID, а потом норм, почему так подскажите? на локал машине все норм...

Answer (score 1):

[TamplerMonkey тоже использует setTimeout](https://github.com/derjanb/tampermonkey/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=setTimeout) .
setTimeout увеличивает глобальный счетчик ID независимо от того, откуда он был вызван.
setInterval также увеличивает счетчик ID.

```
var timer = 0;
function test() {
    ++timer;
    console.log(timer);
    setTimeout(test, 5000);
}
test();

// Увеличиваем счетчик id
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){}, 100);
}
```

Comment: Damilon подскажите как решить проблему?!

Comment: Обновил ответ, обратите внимание что timer нужно увеличивать во всех функциях, где вы вызываете setTimeout;